# Difference between position of argument in running shell script from cygwin prompt

Tags: cygwin, sh

I have been running shell script through cygwin terminal.

I could not figure out what's the difference between :

```
sh script1.sh argument="john" 

 argument="john" sh script.sh
```

Comment: Is this a question about cygwin or `sh`?

Comment: Both actually, as i am trying to run shell script through cygwin.

Comment: It's unlikely that this is being caused by cygwin. I've updated your tagging to help get the right eyes on your question.

Answer (score 0):

CygWin, by default, uses the `bash` shell so this is really a `bash` question. You can see the difference by using the following `script1.sh`:

```
echo "env[argument] = '$argument'"
echo "parameter     = '$1'"
```

and examining the following transcript:

```
pax > sh script1.sh argument="john"
env[argument] = ''
parameter     = 'argument=john'

pax> argument="john" sh script1.sh
env[argument] = 'john'
parameter     = ''
```

The first variant simply passes the string (dequoted) as a *parameter* to the script.

The second sets an environment variable for the duration of the script then runs it with *no* parameters. This particular case is covered in the `bash` documentation (slightly paraphrased):

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments of the form `name=value`. These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.